# react-native can not find JAVA_HOME

Tags: react-native

After initializing my project with `react-native init AwesomeProject` I try to run it in the simulator via `react-native run-android` 
However I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.


error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development     environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

However I followed the [Getting Started Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) and the JAVA_HOME Evironmental Variable is set and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin` is also in the Path var.

I am trying this on Windows 10 with the WSL bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by creating a new project. The problem was that I run `react-native init AwesomeProject` from the WSL bash in windows. I could reproduce this.
When running the same init command in the command prompt it works.