# Persistent React Native problem: JAVA_HOME is not set

Tags: java, android, windows, react-native, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a React Native app for Android on Windows 10, but every time I use `react-native run-android` I get the same Error: `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.`

[I've already set up this variable via the Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GROGy.png)

[And I've set up the Path variable to both the JDK and JRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKVTu.png)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the JDK and Android Studio, I have tried removing and adding "\bin" to both the Path and JAVA_HOME variables, and I've been browsing similar questions (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857694/react-native-can-not-find-java-home) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55883754/java-home-is-not-set-error-after-running-react-native-app)) to no avail.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set the environment for react native, I usually use these settings.

Add the variable **JAVA_HOME** to the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231`

And I add to the system path:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It worked! I'd tried what you suggested, only instead of writing `%ANDROID_HOME%`, I wrote the whole path. Somehow yours worked, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

this works for me to 
Add the variable `JAVA_HOME` to the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231`

And I add to the system path: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator%ANDROID_HOME%\tools%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`